# installing PIL for python 3.4

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have python 3.4 , and 2.7 installed on a ubuntu 14.4. 
I want to install PIL (or pillow if you wish...) on 3.4 but when I try :

```
$ sudo pip install pillow
```

It installs it on python 2.7
How do I make it install pillow on python3.4?

Comment: yes jonsharpe is correct it is either pip3 or pip3.4, when you enter pip in bash hit tab and you will see what options you have

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `pip3 install pillow`. You may need `sudo`.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is correct on the specified system version, I can confirm because I use the same system.

Comment: I'm having a bad time trying to install pip3, apt-get cant find it. how can I install it?

Comment: @almogm it is installed already did you try hitting tab like I suggested?

Comment: @almog type `pip` then hit  `tab` and tell me what you see

Comment: @PadraicCunningham only pip and pip2

Comment: @almog download this then https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and run it with `sudo  python3 get-pip.py`

Comment: Great success! You're the best @PadraicCunningham !

Answer (score 0):

sudo python3 -m pip install pillow
raspberry pi
python 3.4